# installing wxpython via pip or easy_install

Tags: python, easy-install, pip

I am running into some problems installing `wxpython` using `pip`.

Here is my current output:

```
[myuserid]% sudo pip install wxpython
Downloading/unpacking wxpython
  Downloading wxPython2.8-win64-devel-2.8.11.0-msvc9x64.tar.bz2 (7.2Mb): 7.2Mb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package wxpython
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/myuserid/build/wxpython/setup.py'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/myuserid/build/wxpython/setup.py'

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1
Storing complete log in /Users/myuserid/.pip/pip.log
```

- I have had a look in the pip.log file but it is totally empty.
- I have tried installing other packages via `pip` and there are no problems, so I'm concluding that `pip` itself is working.

I have also tried via `easy_install` and got the following:

```
[myuserid]% sudo easy_install wxpython
install_dir /Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/6.2/lib/python2.6/site-packages/
Searching for wxpython
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/wxpython/
Reading http://wxPython.org/
Reading http://wxPython.org/download.php
Best match: wxPython src-2.8.11.0
Downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/wxpython/wxPython-src-2.8.11.0.tar.bz2
Processing wxPython-src-2.8.11.0.tar.bz2
error: Couldn't find a setup script in /tmp/easy_install-faZZOn/wxPython-src-2.8.11.0.tar.bz2
```

- Does this mean that there is something going on with the `wxpython` package as grabbed by `pip` and `easy_install`
- Aside from building from source, are there any other ways to debug or patch this type of response from `pip` or `easy_install`?

**System Config:**

- OS X 10.6
- Enthought Python Distribution Python v2.6, 64-bit

If there is any other information needed, please advise and I will post it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be new to this... welcome!

The folk at Enthought, who built EPD for you still haven't figured out how to reliably build wxPython for a 64-bit python, see here:

http://www.enthought.com/products/epdfaq.php#mac

So, you are treading into difficult waters. Have you considered going the Qt route? All traitsUI backed apps will easily port over to Qt. Currently, I like the looks of Homebrew for interacting with EPD (e.g. for installing pyQt), but the jury is still out (haven't done it yet). I'd post a link to that too, but I am a 1-point user at present...

Another possiblity would be to *also* install the 32-bit EPD which already includes wxPython for you. You might then use your 32-bit python for visualization and your 64-bit for serious number crunching.

If you do insist on installing wxPython, note that you won't be able to link the Carbon version (which is stable, but only 32-bit). Instead, you'll want to use wxCocoa (experimental, 64-bit). At least, this is my understanding. The Enthought folk don't make any mention of wxCocoa, and I wouldn't be surprised if there is breakage. TraitsUI is complex and difficult to debug, so be forewarned if you go this route!

Answer (score 7):

wxPython does not include a `setup.py` file so neither `easy_install` or `pip` will be able to build it that way. Have a look at [these instructions at the wxPython website](http://wxpython.org/builddoc.php) as well as [these instructions at the Enthought website](https://svn.enthought.com/enthought/ticket/1178) to get an idea of how to build wxPython. Unfortunately, I've never built it (I don't use the Enthought version of Python) so I can't help you further than that. Good luck!

Comment: Ok - thanks.  Any idea why they distribute it this way? Why are the libraries themselves and the Python wrapper bundled like this?  To me it makes it confusing to build, especially as from pypi it appears as a regular Python package (i.e. with the py prefix).

Comment: I'm fairly new to Python myself, but my guess is that it's because there are many configure options that need to be set that vary by platform and other reasons. That way, there's no *easy* way to install it.

Answer (score 6):

I don't use the EPD, but I had the same issue. It turned out [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) has a formula to install both `wxWidget` and `wxPython`. It works like a charm. Run the following command:

```
brew install --python wxmac
```

Comment: As per Homebrew's info, you should also use the `--devel` flag to build the experimental 64-bit build. The above won't work with a 64-bit python binary. (`brew info wxmac` says: "wxWidgets 2.8.x builds 32-bit only, so you probably won't be able to use it for other Homebrew-installed software. You can try to build with --devel to get the wxWidgets 2.9.x (unstable) for 64-bit and cocoa support.")

Comment: I wish I could upvote you twice, sir.

Answer (score 1):

This command line works for me with Debian 7.1 64-bit:

```
sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk2.8 python-wxtools wx2.8-i18n libwxgtk2.8-dev libgtk2.0-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

As per [home page instructions](http://wiki.wxpython.org/How%20to%20install%20wxPython#Installing_wxPython-Phoenix_using_pip):

Make sure you have at least version 6.0.8 of pip and 12.0.5 for setuptools.

Install requirements for Linux as [outlined in the README document](https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/blob/master/README.rst).

Install wxPython-Phoenix (Linux):

```
sudo pip install --upgrade \
    --trusted-host wxpython.org --pre -f \
    http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/ wxPython_Phoenix
```

Install wxPython-Phoenix (Windows, use the appropriate script folder):

```
C:\python27\scripts\pip.exe install --upgrade \
    --trusted-host wxpython.org --pre -f \
    http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/ wxPython_Phoenix
```