# Trying to install wxpython, but having multiple errors no matter how I try to do it

Tags: macos, terminal, python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [installing wxpython via pip or easy_install](https://superuser.com/questions/196197/installing-wxpython-via-pip-or-easy-install)

I'm very new to Python and using the terminal, and I'm having a lot of trouble downloading wxpython. I'm using Mac OS X Lion, the most recent version, and I've tried two methods:

1. If I try sudo pip install wxpython, I get:

   ```
   Downloading/unpacking wxpython
   Downloading wxPython2.8-win64-devel-2.8.12.1-msvc9x64.tar.bz2 (7.2Mb): 7.2Mb downloaded
   Running setup.py egg_info for package wxpython
     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
     IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/michelletyler1/build/wxpython/setup.py'
     Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
     Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "<string>", line 14, in <module>

   IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/michelletyler1/build/wxpython/setup.py'
   ```
2. I also tried sudo port install py27-wxpython after installing MacPorts, and got:

   ```
   --->  Computing dependencies for py27-wxpython
   --->  Building py27-wxpython
   Error: org.macports.build for port py27-wxpython returned: command execution failed
   Please see the log file for port py27-wxpython for details:
      /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarbal        ls_ports_python_py-wxpython/py27-wxpython/main.log
   To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
       http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
   Error: Processing of port py27-wxpython failed
   ```

Also, I've been trying to figure out how to change my $PATH so that /usr/local/bin is ahead of /usr/bin (as advised by brew doctor), but when I go to edit my ~/.profile (what I've gathered I'm supposed to do from what I've found online so far), it doesn't work.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you have a `.bash_profile` file as well? If that exists, `.profile` is never read. So you'd need to edit the former. Also, what does the log from your `port install` command say? Note that you preferably shouldn't use both Homebrew and MacPorts simultaneously. `brew doctor` should have told you that.

Answer (score 0):

try downloading an installer: http://downloads.sourceforge.net/wxpython/wxPython2.8-osx-unicode-2.8.12.1-universal-py2.7.dmg

Also, make sure you run your python code in 32 bit mode... i.e.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python-32

import wx
```